# Webpage starts weirdly zoomed in and is fixed after zooming out and then in

Tags: html

Like the title says, when I open my html file, it looks weirdly zoomed in. I checked the browser setting and its at 100% zoom. But what is even weirder, when I zoom out to 90% and then zoom in again to 100%, the webpage looks like how I intended it to look like.

I am very new to web development. Any clue as to what might be causing this issue?s

Edited to make question clearer:
This is what I have in my head tag.
I only use css, no scss or anything like that. I write code in visual studio.

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">


<!-- Personal CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage_style.css">

<!-- Google Font "Karla" -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla">

<!-- Font Awesome Library -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f4b0af8bdd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<title>My Portfolio</title>
```

Comment: Without code, no we'd just be guessing. Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, and it works well for me. So by the look of it, it should be the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">` line.

This line makes your page adapt to the user's screen resolution and scale. As we may have different screen resolutions, or simply the body I used to test ( a simple *Lorem Ipsum* ) could be so much different than yours, it didn't gave me that issue.

As I don't know the contents of your website, i will recommend you to remove the `shrink-to-fit=yes` as it should be what it is causing this.

That may affect other contents, so maybe you could use some Bootstrap ( you may already be using it ) to readjust some parts of the page if they get misconfigured.